# What is the difference between these two input impedance equations?

Tags: impedance, input-impedance, em

I'm currently solving some university E&M homework problems and to solve input impedance, we were given this formula (from Fundamentals of Applied Electromagnetics 6th Ed):

[image]

But when I browse online on the subject matter, the presented formulas are overwhelmingly as follows:
[image]

I'm totally stumped on the difference between these two, I read through both derivations and don't understand how they arrive to this conclusion. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the definitions of each term from each of the sources?

Comment: Yes. They all correspond exactly the same which is even more confusing.

Comment: They are the same equation if ZR = ZL * Z0.